# R - Prevent aggregate function from converting date time timezones to local time?

Tags: r, datetime, timezone

Is there a way to stop `aggregate` converting datetimes to the computer's local timezone? For example:

```
dtUTC <- as.POSIXct(c('2010-01-01 01:01:01', '2015-01-02 07:23:11',
                      '2016-06-02 05:23:41', '2018-01-08 17:57:43'), tz='UTC')
groups <- c(1,1,2,2)
result <- aggregate(dtUTC, by=list(groups), FUN=min)
```

The result is converted to my computers local timezone.

```
> dtUTC
[1] "2010-01-01 01:01:01 UTC" "2015-01-02 07:23:11 UTC" "2016-06-02 05:23:41 UTC"
[4] "2018-01-08 17:57:43 UTC"
> result$x
[1] "2010-01-01 12:01:01 AEDT" "2016-06-02 15:23:41 AEST"
```

I can convert it back post hoc but this is an annoying extra step to have to do. Especially if I have multiple datetime columns.

```
attr(result$x, 'tzone') <- 'UTC'
> result$x
[1] "2010-01-01 01:01:01 UTC" "2016-06-02 05:23:41 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `dplyr` package to aggregate

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
dtUTC <- as.POSIXct(c('2010-01-01 01:01:01', '2015-01-02 07:23:11',
                      '2016-06-02 05:23:41', '2018-01-08 17:57:43'), tz='UTC')
groups <- c(1,1,2,2)
b<-data.frame(date= dtUTC, group = groups) %>% group_by(group) %>% dplyr::summarise(min = min(date))
b$min


> b$min
[1] "2010-01-01 01:01:01 UTC" "2016-06-02 05:23:41 UTC"
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't find anything that you can do with `aggregate` to change this behavior, but you can set your environment's TZ so any date-times will automatically be in UTC:

```r
Sys.setenv(TZ='UTC') # <- set your TZ here

dtUTC <- as.POSIXct(c('2010-01-01 01:01:01', '2015-01-02 07:23:11',
                      '2016-06-02 05:23:41', '2018-01-08 17:57:43'))
groups <- c(1,1,2,2)

df <- data.frame(dtUTC, groups)
result <- aggregate(dtUTC ~ groups, df, min)

result$dtUTC

# [1] "2010-01-01 01:01:01 UTC" "2016-06-02 05:23:41 UTC"
```

Comment: Thank's @gersht. I upvoted your answer as it's a good solution but for other reasons, I'd rather not change my environment's tzone.